# Php script file download

Tags: php, file, get

**Brief description**
I'm trying to download png which is kept beside php file in same folder.

Below is my `test2.php` code

```
$file_name = $_GET['home.png'];
$file_url = 'http://192.168.0.113:90/download-test/' . $file_name;
header('Content-Type: application/png');
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
readfile($file_url);
exit;
```

`test2.html` code

```
<a href="test2.php?file=home.png">File1</a>
```

> Error : File which is downloaded is test2.php where it should have been home.png.

Please guide what is wrong in the above code.

Comment: `$_GET['home.png']` is a typo. It should read as `$_GET['file']` as per the request `test2.php?file` <<

Comment: saw your comment right as I posted my answer... i'll delete it so you can post the answer if you want? @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @Isaac it's up to you Isaac. I'd leave it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `<a href="test2.php?file=home.png">File1</a>` is what you need to `$_GET` in your first line you're using `$file_name = $_GET['home.png'];` Change that to

```
$file_name = $_GET['file'];
```

and it should do what you want it to do

Comment: Good answer Isaac. I didn't know you were typing up an answer for it when I was typing up my comment. Always glad to support a good answer :-)

Comment: thank you:) was a fairly simple typo to spot, so I put the blinders on and typed it out as quickly and concisely as I could to beat anyone else to the punch! you're just too quick!:P

Comment: One never knows who is looking ;-) *heh!* oh, and you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problems are that you aren't defining your variable in the correct way. It should be

```
$file_name = $_GET['file'];
```

Also, `readfile()`'s first parameter can't be an URL if you want to download a local file. If it's at the same folder, `$file_url` is just the file name with extension.

Also, I recommend you first checking the variable to see if it exists (using `isset()`), and also check that it isn't pointing to a PHP file or something in another folder (preventing it from having ..) before returning the file to the client.

Comment: *"I recommend you first checking the variable to see if it exists (using isset()),"* - I'd use `empty()` since `isset()` can be considered as being set. Plus, I'd also check if the file exists with `file_exists()`. `isset()` doesn't check to see if it exists (on the server).

Comment: Technically speaking `readfile` can use a URL as per this quote here **A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen_wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.**